# switch for http status code

Tags: javascript, express

How can I do a switch statement to return error message based on the http status code, I did this:

```
switch(true){
    case err.status.test(/^4/): // 4xx
       res.fail(err.status, err);
       break;
    case err.status.test(/^5/): // 5xx
       res.error(err.status, err.message, {data: err});
       break;
```

Is my regex doing it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test()` is a `RegExp` method, so it should be:

```
case /^4/.test(err.status):
```

I personally think `switch(true) { ... }` is a confusing coding style. I would write it as:

```
switch(Math.floor(err.status/100)) {
    case 4:
       res.fail(err.status, err);
       break;
    case 5:
       res.error(err.status, err.message, {data: err});
       break;
}
```

Comment: I know the keyword `break` is in your "..." but I think it could be confusing to do not specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

one can also try making an error object, where keys will the status code and value will be the respective error/success message. For example

```
errorObj = {1 : 'Informational responses', 2: 'Success', ...}
console.log(errorObj[Math.floor(err.status/100)])
```

It serves the purpose in less number of lines most of the time.